# Debug value of Selector

Tags: debugging, testing, css-selectors, selector, testcafe

Maybe a simple question but I completely fail to solve it myself.

How to debug/output the value of a selector?

```
await t
            .expect(Selector('.progress-bar.progress-bar-success').getStyleProperty('width')).eql('100%', {timeout: 90000})
```

I tried to use

```
console.log(Selector('.progress-bar.progress-bar-success').getStyleProperty('width'));
```

and also with .value at the end. But I do not get any information. 
Is any tip available?

Answer (score 5):

[Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/creating-selectors.html) returns a Promise. You need to wait until the promise was resolved. To do this, just add the `await` keyword before the Selector call.

```js
console.log(await Selector('.progress-bar.progress-bar-success').getStyleProperty('width'));
```